# why the hidden form not shown?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

i have the following code that has button and `click` on it should display the `hidden` form. but it does not, why?

```
@model EmployeesTest.Models.EmployeeVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<input type="submit" name="name" value="New Entry" id="new"/>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <div id="frm" style="visibility:hidden">
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.emp.FirstName)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.emp.FirstName)</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.emp.FirstName)</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.emp.LastName)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.emp.LastName)</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.emp.LastName)</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Save"/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
        </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#new').click(function () {
                (this).preventDefault();

                $('#frm').css('visibility', 'visible');

            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm jQuery is actually loading?

Comment: @RajeshJNair Uncaught TypeError: this.preventDefault is not a function

Comment: Just remove the line `(this).preventDefault();` - its not doing anything (best guess is that you were trying to prevent the default action - but there is none - in which case it would have needed to be `$('#new').click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); ... })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `(this).preventDefault` and pass `event` as argument and prevent it as below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#new').click(function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $('#frm').css('visibility', 'visible');
    });
});
```

> Since the type of `button` is just `button` there is no need to
>   prevent its default action.

Comment: No real need to `event.preventDefault();` in this case (its just a `type="button"`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke.. Yea.. mentioned it.. :)

Comment: Saw the edit just as I added the comment (and cancelled out that stupid down vote)

Comment: No probs @StephenMuecke.. I don't know but I still have one `downvote`.. I think the guy has downvoted and left the question... :D

Comment: @StephenMuecke let me rename type="button" to submit

Comment: @PhillGreggan.. There is no use of making `button` to `submit` unless you have any `form` to submit for that `button`. If this is the only functionality i.e. hiding and showing `form` then just `type=button` is enough..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao the code i have now (after mods) iv added a 'form'.. ealier i there was no form so let me update that too  )

Comment: @PhillGreggan, Guruprasad Rao is correct. It should just be `<button type="button" ...` as per your original (its not a submit element)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#new').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#frm').css('visibility', '');
    });
});
```